# Grammar mistake in Suspension message for Excessive discussion in comments

Tags: bug, account-suspension, grammatical-correction

When visiting a profile of a user suspended for *excessive discussion in comments* the public suspension message on the user's profile is missing a "for" or similar to complete the sentence.

It reads:

[image: "This account is temporarily suspended excessive discussion in comments. The suspension period ends in 4 days."]

> This account is temporarily suspended excessive discussion in comments. The suspension period ends in 4 days.

I believe this should be updated to say "This account is temporarily suspended **for** (or **due to**) excessive discussion in comments.".

Comment: Just a note that this is a known issue due to a recent update in Mod tools.

Comment: Can someone explain how someone could incur this infraction?

Comment: You can be suspended just for excessive discussion in comments? I thought to get suspended, you had to do really bad things.

Comment: @user16217248 well, [excessive discussion is not recommended in the comment thread](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: *[due to](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/due_to#Preposition)*?

Comment: You can be suspended for too many comments? My days are numbered.

Comment: No comment ... :-)

Comment: You can be suspended for any behaviour when Mods have told you to stop that.